# How to Copy dependencies to Build directory in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How to Copy dependencies to Build directory in Gradle without adding any tasks in build.gradle like mvn dependency:copy-dependencies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want a task for this you could use the `copy` method of the `project` object.

```
configurations {
    compile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'someGroup:someArtifact:someVersion'
}

project.copy {
    from project.configurations.compile
    into project.buildDir
}
```

One noticeable effect of this is that the resolving will be triggered for every invokation i.e. even if you only want to list tasks the resolve and copy will be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your solution....my requirement is ..need to get dependencies without touching build.gradle... I have around 1500+ grAdle projects....need to copy dependencies for each project into its build directory as part of prebuild.....is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess you could reuse the copy instruction and inject it using the `subprojects` DSL if you have a rootProject. But for 1500+ projects I guess this will be a heavy operation in any case.

Comment: Since the dependency configuration 'compile' is now deprecated and it's been replaced by implementation and api, how would you copy if you use either of them?

Comment: @Glund You can of course use any other namend configuration instead of `compile`, e.g. you can change to: `from project.configurations.compileOnly`

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the dependencies based on the configuration types.

Here is some examples

```
def runtimeDependencies = "${buildDir}/libs/runtime_dependencies/"
def compileDependencies = "${buildDir}/libs/compile_dependencies/"


task copyRuntimeDeps(type: Copy) {

    from configurations.runtime
    into "${runtimeDependencies}"


}

task compileDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into "${compileDependencies}"
}
```

You can add this task into the build.gradle and execute the task as `gradle compileDeps`

All the possible configurations can be seen with `configurations.each { println it.name }`