# Gradle Project: Copy Dependencies to Build Directory

Tags: gradle

How do I copy my project's dependencies to the build directory?

This is a very common question. I've searched and found many threads that answer this exact question, but none of the solutions are working. Here are three threads (some are quite old) that give solutions that I am unable to get working.

[Gradle equivalent to Maven's "copy-dependencies"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697999/gradle-equivalent-to-mavens-copy-dependencies)

[How to Copy dependencies to Build directory in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567864/how-to-copy-dependencies-to-build-directory-in-gradle)

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-gather-all-my-projects-dependencies-into-a-folder/7146

FYI, I've tried, among others:

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into 'dependencies'
}

task copyDependencies2(type: Copy) {
    from project.configurations.compile
    into project.buildDir
}

project.copy {
    from project.configurations.compile
    into project.buildDir
}
```

If possible, I prefer current recommended best practices methods rather than older deprecated methods. I'm staying on the current Gradle, which is  currently 4.7 as of this writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to use the built-in "distribution" plugin.

```java
plugins {
    id 'distribution'
}

group 'org.yourorg'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
}

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from jar // copies your jar
            from(project.configurations.runtime) // copies dependency jars
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can run one command which will compile and assemble in a single step:

```java
gradlew installDist
```

This creates the distribution as a directory structure under ./build/install/
Furthermore, you can create the distribution as a zip under ./build/distributions/

```java
gradlew distZip
```

If you want to separate the built jar from the dependencies, this is conventional:

```java
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from jar
            into('lib') {
                from(project.configurations.runtime)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm getting this error: `Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.`

Answer (score 5):

OK, after playing with this for several hours, I have a solution that works. This is very different from older solutions which don't seem to work on current versions of Gradle. This one works on Gradle 4.7:

```
task jarWithDeps(dependsOn: 'jar', type: Copy) {
  def conf = configurations.runtimeClasspath
  from conf.allDependencies.collect { conf.files(it) }
  into "${project.buildDir}/libs"
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, using gradle version 6.1.1 I believe. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time trying to fix that. This works on Gradle 7.4.1

```
task copyAllDependencies(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compileClasspath
  into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
}
build.dependsOn(copyAllDependencies)
```

[image]